# Npgsql, error during saving a DateTime value (null value in column "CreatedAt" violates not-null constraint)

Tags: c#, datetime, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have the following model:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Category { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
}
```

And the following application context:

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _connectionString;

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("Sportshop");
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("Web"));
    }
}
```

Next I will show you a screen of my PostgreSQL data base schema:

[image]

I'm trying to save a new entity with the help of the next code:

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        Product product = new Product
        {
            Name = "P1",
            Category = "test",
            Price = 1000,
            Description = "Hello !!!"
        };

        _applicationContext.Products.Add(product);
        _applicationContext.SaveChanges();


        return View(// ... some view data);
    }
```

But as the result I see this error. I don't understand why.

[image]

I absolutely sure that `CreatedAt`field is not null during the saving. See a screen of debug:

[image]

Where is the mistake?

Comment: it can be a classic date time format issue.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your property indeed has a value, but it is also decorated with `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]`.

By using `Computed`, you are telling EF Core that it must leave the property's value upto the database. In other words, the database is made fully responsible for generating or computing a value during every query. As can be read [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute), "*The practical effect of this is that Entity Framework will not include the property in INSERT or UPDATE statements*".

The generated insert statement will then look like

```
INSERT INTO Products (Id, Name, Description, Category, Price) ...
```

Which will fail because `CreatedAt` has a NOT NULL setting, apparently without a default value.

You can try [giving the field a default value using the Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-values):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .Property(b => b.CreatedAt)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");
}
```

This should work as long as it is supported for Npgsql, which I don't know for sure. If it does not work then you may have no other option but to remove the attribute and take value creation in your own hands.

Comment: Should I make a new migration to update DatabaseGEneration behavior? (I'm going to set it manually) I have tried this and EF told me that `column "CreatedAt" of relation "Products" already exist`

Comment: Ok, I should not update migration. I have to just remove `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]` for manually setting `CreatedAt` Interesting that before I read your answer I had update EF from 2.2.4 to 2.2.6 and EF set me default value for date `0001-01-01 00:00:00.000000`. After your answer I understand all clear, all is working! Thank you very much!

Comment: To add to the above, PostgreSQL does not support computed columns (except via triggers) and so `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` does not have an effect in the database. But it still triggers the EF Core behavior of not sending the value to the database as explained above. If the intent is to automatically populate the column with the timestamp *at creation* (which is very different from a computed column), the default value can be configured via EF Core to call `NOW()` or any other valid PostgreSQL expression.

Comment: modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .Property(b => b.CreatedAt)
        .HasDefaultValueSql("now()"); <---  Use this.